# Phonegap BarcodeScanner close button not working after update xcode to xcode 6

Tags: cordova, ios8, xcode6

I have made an application using xcode5, and using this plugin, it was working good actually as expected, then the client asked for some changes, so I had to update my xcode to xcode 6 to make it compatible with ios8, after I did this, I ran my app and the close button from the scanner crashed out, or at least it does not do anything at all, it does not close the camera and the user cannot continue the navigation for the other portions of the app.

Has anyone experienced something similar like this? I really need some help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you update to `cordova 3.6.3`? Also, not all plugins have been updated for iOS8 support yet, this may be a bug that needs to be reported

Comment: Could you please mention plugin used here .

Comment: I think I am using cordova 3.5.0, but I dont think that this may be the issue since the plugin was working good... And sure the plugin I am using is this onehttps://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeDemo.git I really apreciate some help on this.. this is freaking me out